# Terracotta for Python world?

Tags: java, python, terracotta

Would you know if something similar to [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/) (in Java world) exists for Python world? [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) ? Or something else.

Comment: Have you considered using Jython?

Comment: Nice suggestion, however I will prefer to stick to CPython for now.
However, who knows how things will be solved for multi-processor world. Maybe Jython would be the way to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Twisted is the best alternative you can find.
Let me warn you that it will give you some headaches, as it forces you to code in a completely different way. But once you understand it, it's not that hard....

http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/howto/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[Pyro](http://pyro.sourceforge.net/) can be used similarly in python as terracotta in java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something that gives you a [Distributed Hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table)/[Tuple Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space) type of implementation, [Entangled](http://entangled.sourceforge.net/) seems to be a Python implementation. I'm sure there are others out there though if you google for them.

Comment: Well Terracotta is a little bit more mature :-)
Entangled looks interesting, but lacks a lot of features. Additionally, it seems that last check-in was made 17 months ago :(

Answer (score 0):

try to run your code with JPython and use Terracotta ;)